# How to stop automatic entry as privileged exec from console login?

Tags: router, cisco-ios

I am configuring my Cisco router and trying to set up access levels.
I was under the impression that level 0 was a very limited mode which almost only allows users to enter the enable command to enter privileged exec. However, I'd expect that if priviliged exec had a password set, that it wouldn't just let me access it without a password, but this seems to be the case.

I did the following:

```
router#config t
router(config)#enable secret somePass
router(config)#line 0
router(line-config)#password passForConsole
router(line-config)#login
router(line-config)#exit
router(config)#exit
router#disable
router exit
```

And I'd expect that after trying to log back in, the password would only grant console access, but it is always logging in as privileged exec `router#`, so it's bypassing my privileged exec password

Why is this happening and how can I change this?

Comment: Line 0 and level 0 are _not_ the same thing.

Comment: I get that now, but then what can I do to fix this? The problem is that login from the console also logs in as privileged exec, even if the user didn't type the privileged exec password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `line` you can define the default `privilege level` that user will get into when logging. Users could later escalate their privilege using `enable`. Keep in mind you have different line options (console, vty, etc)

To answer your question - you can simply do `privilege level 1` under `line` settings of the method you want to configure (virtual/console).

For further reference check out [this](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/optical/cpt/r9_3/configuration/guide/cpt93_configuration/cpt93_configuration_chapter_010000.pdf) paper.